# Why JQuery AJAX call is not working?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

The following is my JQuery AJAX method:

```
function meFun() {
    alert('enter');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "About.aspx/GetRes",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Do something interesting here.
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
    alert('end');

}
```

The following is my button code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="meFun();" value="Click me" id="btn" />
```

Folling is my function in About.aspx

```
Public Function GetRes() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

The `meFun()` method is called successfully but doesn't call the `GetRes()` and the AJAX call doesn't return any response.

Any idea why? Also, please suggest a good way to debug these sorts of AJAX problems.

Comment: Try specifying an error callback for the ajax request, not just a success callback.

Comment: does jquery is loaded..?

Comment: What is the HTTP status code you get in this AJAX request?
use statusCode function of this AJAX call.

For AJAX debugging i use firefox's Plugin Firebug, where i can see in console my AJAX request, parameters and response from the server.

Comment: @DipeshParmar jquery is loaded successfully.

Comment: Are you sure that `GetRes()` is a method which returns the `json`? `Do you get any errors in the console?`

Comment: try adding`-->` : `error : function(err){alert(err);}` after success.

Comment: @user1387147 please try to encode true response in json i think that is conflicting...because i had same issue before..i just returned true or false from script while ajax call expected json response so it showed me errors...try it

Comment: for debugging javascript theres nothing better than the web developer tools that all modern browsers provide either out of the box or through extension downloads. in chrome/IE/firefox(if firebug installed) hit f12 and it will come up. you can set custom breakpoints and watch expressions to pause your code and step through it as well as monitor the http traffic. the http traffic will first tell you if the ajax is even making a call to the server. That's a good start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have the WebMethod attribute on your server side GetRes function (this is in C#, I don't know how you do that in VB) and make GetRes static (or whatever the equivalent in VB is).

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool GetRes()
{
  return true;
}
```

Then, add the `error` handlers to your jQuery `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "About.aspx/GetRes",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Do something interesting here.
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
    alert('end');
```

EDIT: to debug, set a breakpoint in the error handler and inspect the `data` parameter. All browsers (well, I can vouch for IE, Firefox (with Firebug) and Chrome) have good script debuggers. If an error occurs, there will be a property in `data`, the name of which eludes me at the moment, that explains the error in detail.

Answer (score 1):

you are returning a data in a STRING FORMAT WHILE YOUR AJAX CALL EXPECTING A JSON FORMAT
SO AT THE SERVER SIDE CONVERT TRUE TO JSON FORMAT BY using newtonsoft library or inbuilt jsonconversion mechanism of asp.net

as mentioned by svajger you have to declare it as webmethod and it must be static the return type is string prefered

and at the success handler you have to parse json data by
JSON.parse method