# Ajax Response is not defeined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am quite green when it comes to AJAX and am trying to get an email address from an ASP.Net code behind function

When using the below code I am getting the error as per the title of this issue.

This is the code I am using

```
$('.txtRequester').focusout(function () {
 console.log("textBox has lost focus");
 function ShowCurrentTime() {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/FindEmailAddress",
  data: '{id: "' + $("txtRequester").val + '" }',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: OnSuccess,
  failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
     }
   });
 }
  function OnSuccess(response) {
   alert(response.d);
  }
});
```

which is an adaptation of the code from this site.

[ASP.Net Snippets](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

When changing the line

`success: OnSuccess` to `success: alert(response)` or `success: alert(data)`

I get the error up, but if I use `success: alert("ok")` I get the message saying ok so I suspect that I am getting into the function as below.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function FindEmailAddress(ByVal id As String) As String
Dim response As String = GetEmail(id)
Return response
End Function
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone to help me and let me know where I am going wrong on this one.

thanks

Comment: why not `success: function(data) { alert(data) }`?

Comment: try `console.log()` you need to get the data from json response like data.email or something like that if that is from your json

Comment: What happens if you do `success: OnSuccess(response)`

Comment: Are you able to call the function? Have set the breakpoint in vb code? Does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: `success: function(data) { alert(data) }` doesn't fire the alert box, and setting the break point in the code does not get hit, but I also get no failure message

Comment: @ahervin when I try this I get the same as `success: function(data) { alert(data) }` no success or failure message

Comment: the code you have written above is this what you are using ?

Comment: `success: function(response){      Onsuccess(response); },` ?

Comment: found my answer here [similar stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151459/why-jquery-ajax-call-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have can check the state of failure by using this code below as I think there is wrong syntax used by you.

```
$('.txtRequester').focusout(function () {
        console.log("textBox has lost focus");
        function ShowCurrentTime() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/FindEmailAddress",
                data: JSON.stringify({id: ' + $(".txtRequester").val() + ' }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data, status, header){
                 console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

then definitely you will get error response, if your success won't hit.

Comment: trying this I don't even get into the `ShowCurrentTime` method

Comment: Try this above updated code. Whether you get any error or success hit?

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the function thats why its never get called.

```
    $('.txtRequester').focusout(function () {
        console.log("textBox has lost focus");
        ShowCurrentTime();

    });

    function ShowCurrentTime() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/FindEmailAddress",
            data: '{id: "' + $("txtRequester").val() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                Onsuccess(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

This will help :)

Comment: the result is stil the same

Comment: change `$("txtRequester").val` to `$("txtRequester").val()` it is also wrong it will give error

Comment: ok, that's getting into the method, but I still get the error response is not defined

Comment: this can be beacause the response cant be parsed to json remove these lines contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType: "json" and check the response

Comment: crosscheck from POSTMAN that your server is giving the right response or not.

Comment: google it, get the postman extension for browser where you cant post/get data to a url

Comment: cant seem to find one for IE (that's the corporate standard I have to develop for )

Answer (score 0):

use ajax directly ,

```
 $('.txtRequester').focusout(function () {
    console.log("textBox has lost focus");

    var cond = $(".txtRequester").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/FindEmailAddress",
            data: {id:cond},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                 alert(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('.txtRequester')` to `$('#txtRequester')`

and

Change `$("txtRequester").val` to `$('#txtRequester').val()`

Comment: that's already been suggested, but I am still getting the same error that response is not defined

Comment: txtRequester is id or class?

Comment: in this instance it is a class that i am getting it on